# Puppet write a command that runs if lookup succeeds?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have the following in my puppet manifest and it works:

```
package {
  lookup('latest_packages'): ensure => latest,
}
```

Now we are adding another option to ensure absent, this lookup can contain values but it can also be non-existent. When the hiera data doesn't exists it causes my manifest to fail.

```
package {
  lookup('latest_packages'): ensure => absent,
}
```

If that data doesn't exists I get back this on the agent:

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on
>   SERVER: Server Error: Function lookup() did not find a value for the
>   name 'removed_packages' on node dev-596e89d2fe5e08410003f2e6

How can I set this up to run only if lookup finds values? Do I need to wrap the package function in a conditional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest path to success here is probably to make use of the default value argument to the `lookup` function. We can also add in the data type and merge behavior just to help focus the lookup:

```
lookup('removed_packages', Array[String], 'unique', [])
```

Also, based on your error message I am guessing the key you are looking up is actually `removed_packages` for the `absent` case.

- `Array[String]`: data type that guarantees your package list will be an array of strings. This helps protect against undesired inputs to this resource from your data.
- `unique`: Combines any number of arrays and scalar values to return a merged and flattened array with all duplicate values removed. This is nice and efficient.
- `[]`: the default value, so that for a nonexistent `removed_packages` key the resource will resolve to:

  `package { []: ensure => absent }`

  which will be a benign and successfully compiled resource in your catalog.

Comment: thanks for the answer. For more info heres the offical documentation of `lookup()`

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.0/hiera_use_function.html